# Parsing URL parameters in XML with BS4

Tags: xml, url, beautifulsoup

Haven't been able to find an answer on the web, so here is my first stackoverflow question :)

With **BeautifulSoup4**, I find it difficult to preserve parameters in a URL when I choose "xml" as the parser. Any workaround?

e.g.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
url = u'<li href="www.example.com/index.php?sky=blue&river=wide"> Hello World </li>'
BS(url, 'xml')
```

I got the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<li href="www.example.com/index.php?sky=blue=wide"> Hello World </li>
```

Note that `?river` is missing in the parsed output.

FYI, with **bs4**, `BeautifulStoneSoup(url)` would give the same undesirable output, since it's just BeautifulSoup with 'xml' parser. However, this is not an issue with **BeautifulStoneSoup** in **BeautifulSoup3**. But I have to use bs4 in my project.

Any fixes for that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't XML. For it to be XML, it must be:

```
<li href="www.example.com/index.php?sky=blue&amp;river=wide">
```

You can't just plop an & into an attribute and expect it to work.